# Error Building a Native App with Sencha 2.3 + PhoneGap

Tags: ios, extjs, cordova, sencha-touch-2, sencha-cmd

I'm following a simple instructions from a video on Vimeo. I upgraded my app from Sencha Touch 2.2 to 2.3. Added PhoneGap support. And now trying to build the native app. It turned out not as easy. I need help with this one:

```
macbook-air:admin Me$ sencha app build -run nativeSencha Cmd v4.0.1.45
[INF]
[INF] init-plugin:
[INF]
[INF] cmd-root-plugin.init-properties:
[INF]
[INF] init-properties:
[INF]
[INF] init-sencha-command:
[INF]
[INF] init:
[INF]
[INF] app-build-impl:
[INF]
[INF] -before-init-local:
[INF]
[INF] -init-local:
[INF]
[INF] -after-init-local:
[INF]
[INF] init-local:
[INF]
[INF] find-cmd-in-path:
[INF]
[INF] find-cmd-in-environment:
[INF]
[INF] find-cmd-in-shell:
[INF]
[INF] init-cmd:
[INF]      [echo] Using Sencha Cmd from /Users/Me/bin/Sencha/Cmd/4.0.1.45 for /Users/Me/App/public/Admin/build.xml
[INF]
[INF] -before-init:
[INF]
[INF] -init:
[INF] Initializing Sencha Cmd ant environment
[INF] Adding antlib taskdef for com/sencha/command/compass/ant/antlib.xml
[INF]
[INF] -after-init:
[INF]
[INF] -before-init-defaults:
[INF]
[INF] -init-defaults:
[INF]
[INF] -after-init-defaults:
[INF]
[INF] -init-compiler:
[INF]
[INF] init:
[INF]
[INF] -before-build:
[INF]
[INF] refresh:
[INF]
[INF] -before-refresh:
[INF]
[INF] -init:
[INF]
[INF] -init-compiler:
[INF]
[INF] -detect-app-build-properties:
[INF] Loading app json manifest...
[ERR]
[ERR] BUILD FAILED
[ERR] java.lang.NullPointerException
[ERR]
[ERR] Total time: 1 second
[ERR] The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/Me/App/public/Admin/.sencha/app/build-impl.xml:367: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/Me/App/public/Admin/.sencha/app/js-impl.xml:11: java.lang.NullPointerException
macbook-air:admin Me$
```

I've uploaded these 2 files on [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w1i7xy7pdjtxyc5/Archive.zip). Also here's a debug output http://pastebin.com/T6ENe8xh Please let me know if there's anything else needed in order to track the problem. Am I missing something? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

P.S. I'm a total beginner when it comes to these stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and rectified it by running:

```
sudo xcodebuild -license
```